# Is earth of a 3-prong AC/DC adapter is connected to the GND of DC output?

Tags: ground, earth

Below is an illustration of a 3-prong AC/DC adapter(such as a laptop adapter):

Here I marked the primary earth ground as 'a'; and GND of the secondary(DC) as 'b'.

My question is are these grounds connected to each other in real?[image]? 
Can I just check it with a multimeter continuity test?

Comment: Yes, you can just check with a multimeter. Did you even try before asking?

Comment: And yes, +1 to Majenko - don't assume when you can test!

Comment: how is in general? is that a known fact? why would they connect it?

Comment: @Majenko, what of the case where only a 2-prong AC connection is used?

Comment: @sherrellbc Then there can be no earth connection since there is no earth.

Comment: Since nobody else commented on it, I will. That schematic is not representative of the typical laptop power supply. The typical laptop power supply uses switching techniques to avoid having a large heavy transformer and to reduce standby power loss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ground is quite often a label for "zero volts" or reference or common. As opposed to "earth" which has a more particular meaning.

Generally speaking our circuit ground is not connected to earth and personally I prefer to use different symbols to emphasise that.

Unless there was a specific requirement for circuit ground to be connected to earth, I would never connect them together. The DC output is then said to be floating (the negative/ground output doesn't have a reference to some other circuit elsewhere on your bench). The main reason to do this is to avoid ground loops that could occur if you connect your microcontroller (say) to another piece of equipment (computer, etc).

Comment: can i make a split power supply by two identical ac/dc adapters safely then?

Comment: can you also tell me what is in an ac/dc adapter is connected to the earth? chasis?

Comment: Yes - I have two power supplies here on my bench, say A and B, where I can connect + of A to - of B. Then -A is -ve rail, +A/-B is zero and +B is +ve rail (hope that's not confusing). My bench supplies also have a green terminal which is actual earth. It's connected to the chassis for safety. I should add that the same does not go for oscilloscopes. The GND on those is almost always actual Earth. Same for laptops and monitors - you can find that out the very hard way!

Comment: im very confused. what do you mean in oscilloscopes and laptop adapters GND is connected to the earth? could you draw if possible i dont understand from your answer.:(

Comment: To clarify: An oscilloscope probe has two parts. The needle probe bit and a ground clip. Many people don't realise that this ground clip is really tied to chassis earth. 90% of the time, GND is not Earth but this is one of those rare occasions. So when you clip it to a point on your circuit, that point is not floating anymore. It's actual Earth. Then you plug in a USB cable, where the ground on the cable is also actual Earth. You've now shorted two points on your circuit via the power supply's earth! I've seen bad things happen :)

Comment: User16307 is confused because first Carveone replied yes, you can connect supplies in series. Then, almost immediately afterward, Carveone said laptop supplies are earth grounded. This is contradictory, hence the confusion. I simply do not know whether typical laptop supplies can be put in series, so I can't answer.

Comment: Ah. I didn't mean that, apologies for the confusion. What I was trying to get across is that *most* DC power supplies will float their outputs. In the case of proper bench supplies for example. But as I typed that, I didn't want to infer that 100% of them do this so I added some examples of devices that don't float. What I hoped to get across is that you don't always know which ones - if you want to know, you really have to test it.